# Dart: Function signature for catchError Future

Tags: dart

I've got some `Future` code that looks like this:

```dart
return login().then((user) {
    print("Logged in user ${user.name}");
    return user;
}).catchError(this.displayError);
```

Where I'm trying to pass a function to the `catchError(...)` function because it's an error handler I'm reusing across a number of calls. I've tried using this:

```dart
Future<void> displayError(Error error) {
    return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) { 
        return AlertDialog(...); 
    });
}
```

But when I run the app I get this error:

```
Invalid argument (onError): Error handler must accept one Object or one Object and a StackTrace as arguments, and return a a valid result: Closure: (Error) => Future<void> from Function 'displayError':.
```

If I change my `catchError(...)` to this:

```dart
.catchError((error) {
    displayError(error);
})
```

Everything then works. My question is does anyone know why I've not been successful passing the `displayError` function to `catchError` instead of call it within a closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the signature of the handler – it must be an `Object` not an `Error`. There are no promises in Dart that thrown objects are of type `Error`. They could be anything.

```dart
Future<void> displayError(Object error) {
    return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) { 
        return AlertDialog(...); 
    });
}
```